# Integrate Sidebar and toolbar of mx-graph-editor with react js

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph

I am naive with this https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph.
I want to create https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html editor like this in react js. Wanted a same toolbar and sidebar too. I checked grapheditor(https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/js) but those js files are not directly usable in react code. So is there any way to import them easily and create this view or some other thing to implement this?

I am able to create simple graph viewer of mxGraph using **mxgraph** library. But how to add sidebar and toolbar. I don't want any custom things there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use react js, but you have to add a div for each bar and add custom buttons with their respective functions. For me, the port example was very useful (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/ports.html)

Comment: Alright. I will check this. actually I have issue with react only it is working with pure js..
Thanks for the response.